# Firestore compound queries in swift error when using multiple whereFeild

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, compound-query

I'm having issues compounding or chaining multiple conditions to a firestore query. the below function works with either of the following 'whereFeild' conditions by themselves, so I know the individual conditions are correct;

".whereField("userID", isEqualTo: id)"

or

"whereField("upsideSummaryUploadTimestamp", isGreaterThan: pastTimestamp)"

but when both (or more) are put together, it returns no data. Is there something wrong with the query logic?

```
private func fetchPastSummaries() {

    let now = Date()
        var dateComponents = DateComponents()
        dateComponents.month = -3
        let pastDate = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian).date(byAdding: dateComponents, to: now)!
        let pastTimestamp = pastDate.timeIntervalSince1970
        
        let id = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
        
        let query = db.collection("call_summeries")
            .whereField("userID", isEqualTo: id)
            .whereField("upsideSummaryUploadTimestamp", isGreaterThan: pastTimestamp)

        query.getDocuments { (querySnapshot, error) in
            guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else { // triggered when more than one 'whereFeild' is added to query.


                print("No documents, fetchPastSummaries()")
                self.pastSummeries = nil // set to nil to continue the chain of fetches.
                return

            }
            
            self.pastSummeries = documents.compactMap { (queryDocumentSnapshot) -> UserCallSummaryModel? in
                return try? queryDocumentSnapshot.data(as: UserCallSummaryModel.self)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you receive error message in console?

Comment: In the future, you should post the error message that you see so that it's clear what's going on.  You would have been able to do a web search on that to easily find the remedy.

Answer (score 0):

Solution to my problem here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/indexing

For any compound queries you must index them first in Firebase.